# Path Mapping Issue in React-TypeScript-Snowpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, snowpack

I am using React, TypeScript and Snowpack in a project. I am facing issue in path mapping.

**This is the folder structure in my project:**

[image]

**`tsconfig.json`**

[image]

**`snowpack.coonfig.js`**

[image]

**`App.tsx`**

[image]

**This is the error I am getting:**

[image]

Can anyone please help me fix this? What am I missing here?
If in `App.tsx`, I `ctrl+click` on `HomePage` import, it takes me to that page but when I run `yarn start`, it gives the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add 'app' alias to snowpack config too so it recognizes it.

https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#alias